# Loops through a whole list

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a pretty simple function where the user is asked to input a list of numbers, then a second input for a second number. If any single number in the first argument is larger than the second argument, then it will return True, and if none of the numbers in the first argument in larger, it should return false. Seems simple enough but I'm struggling to get it to loop through the entire list before it returns the boolean value. A new problem I'm having throws up an error and says I'm trying to compare int's to lists with the `>` operator.

```
def num_gt(list_num, single_num):

    #breakpoint()
    for i in list_num :
        if i > single_num :
            return True
        else:
             return False


list_num = (input("Please enter list numbers: "))

single_num = (input("Please enter single number: "))

list_num = list(map(int, list_num))

single_num = list(map(int, single_num))
```

Not sure where I'm goinging wrong here. The inputs get converted to lists of integers, and stepping through it shows its return lists as it should. Any help appreciated

Comment: Why do you make `single_num` into a *list* if it's only supposed to be a *single* number?

Comment: use `single_num = int(single_num)` in place of the last line. right now it is a list, with this line, it becomes an int, which I assume was the initial intent

Answer (score 1):

You need to not cast your single num to a list as it is a single value.

Remove the line.

```
single_num = list(map(int, single_num))
```

And replace with:

```
single_num = int(single_num)
```

Your function is also slightly wrong as it will only check one value then always return. It should instead check all the values and only if all of them are smaller then return false.

```
def num_gt(list_num, single_num):

    #breakpoint()
    for i in list_num :
        if i > single_num :
            return True
    return False
```

Now your function will check all the values and then if none of them return True, it will return False at the end.